# Cannot click on link inside element because blur causes it too disappear first (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a dynamic search input that displays results as you type them. The problem is I added a `blur` event with jQuery to remove a darkened background and some other style when losing focus on the input field.

I also remove the div which has the results in it (because when not focused it doesn't make sense to keep it in the screen).

Inside that div are anchor tags to the result page but when I click them the div just closes due to the `blur` and does not open the link. How can I stop that behaviour?

My html:

```
<div id="searchresultfaq" class="searchresultfaq">
</div>
```

My jQuery that uses blur:

```
$("body").on("focus",".searchTerm2",function(e){
    $('.absoluteoverlay').show();
});

$("body").on("blur",".searchTerm2",function(e){
    $('.absoluteoverlay').hide();
    $( "#searchresultfaq" ).hide();
});
```

The part that posts with Ajax and returns the div with anchor tags:

```
$('.searchTerm2').keyup(function(e) {
clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        $( "#searchresultfaq" ).hide();
    }else{
        if (e.keyCode == 13){
            searchfaq(true);
        }else{
            $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(searchfaq, 500));
        }
    }
});

function searchfaq(force) {
var zoekterm = $(".searchTerm2").val();
    $.ajax({
     type:'post',
     url:"includes/faqsearchresults.php",
     data:({zoekterm: zoekterm}),
     success:function(data){
         $( "#searchresultfaq" ).show().empty().append( data );
     }
 });
}
```

I tried removing it on clicking `absoluteoverlay` instead but this didn't work. Is there a jquery solution to this?

The entire HTML (searchbar and results that are generated below)

```
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="zoekblok">
    <div class="zoekblokwidth vertical-center">
      <div class="search" style="z-index: 1;">
        <input type="text" class="searchTerm2" placeholder="Zoek naar antwoorden" style="border: 2px solid rgb(210, 210, 210);">
        <button type="submit" class="searchButton" style="background: rgb(210, 210, 210); border: 2px solid rgb(210, 210, 210);">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
       </button>
      </div>
     <div id="searchresultfaq" class="searchresultfaq" style="display: block;">
       <div class="absoluteresults">
         <span>Resultaten (9)</span>
       </div>
        <a href="https://google.nl" class="resultrow">
          <span class="resultcat">Wat is de levertijd?</span>
          <span class="resultcontent">De standaard levertijd is 5 productiedagen + 1 ...</span>
        </a>
        <a href="https://google.nl" class="resultrow">
          <span class="resultcat">Wat zijn de leveringsvoorwaarden?</span>
          <span class="resultcontent">Als je order bij ons binnenkomt dan beoordelen ...</span>
        </a>
        <a href="https://google.nl" class="resultrow">
          <span class="resultcat">Leveren jullie op feestdagen?</span>
          <span class="resultcontent">Wij leveren niet in het weekend, op feestdagen ...</span>
        </a>
        <a href="https://google.nl" class="resultrow">
          <span class="resultcat">Wanneer ontvang ik mijn factuur?</span>
          <span class="resultcontent">De factuur ontvang je na levering</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="searchresultsbutton">
          <button type="button" class="btnstyle" name="button">Bekijk alle 9 resultaten</button>
        </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `blur` is not a suitable event for this. Listening `mouseleave` on the div might work better.

Comment: @Teemu Doesn't that close the div even when not clicking outside it but just by moving the cursor out of it? I only want to have it close if a user clicks outside the input field or the result div.

Comment: Yes, that would happen. If you want to "close" the div when user clicks outside, why not listen clicks on `body`, and check which element was clicked. If it's not the div or any of its children, then "close" the div. Could you please add all the related HTML, include `.searchTerm2` and the link too.

Comment: @Teemu I've added the source code that is generated when I type something in the search input.

Comment: @Wimanicesir The inline style is added by jQuery

Answer (score 3):

The trick that worked for me in a similar case is to use `Event.preventDefault()` on the `mousedown` of the link. The click will still occur but it will not trigger the blur.

i don't see the code were you generate the links. But with jQuery you should use something like this on the links (the `a` elements):

```
$("a").on("mousedown", ev => ev.preventDefault());
```

Simple Example: A link will show when the input is focused and can be clicked

```js
$("#link").hide()
$("#input").on("focus", () => $("#link").show());
$("#input").on("blur", () => $("#link").hide());
$("#link").on("click", () => { alert("clicked"); console.log("clicked") });
// comment this out to see that the click won't be triggered without it
$("#link").on("mousedown",  ev => ev.preventDefault());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
<a href="javascript:" id="link">some link</a>
```